# I want to use a stored cookie in my desktop at another computer to login a webpage

Tags: php, cookies

[image]

I got Chrome's cookie file in my desktop. I heard that auto login uses a cookie to verify the user.
I cleared the cookie in my desktop and auto login at www.naver.com, which made new cookie.
I sent this file to another computer, but I can't auto login www.naver.com.
What should I do to use this cookie file?

Comment: It's going to depend hugely on what naver,com do with their cookies. There's no generic answer to this. I'd also hope it doesn't work, as there aren't many legitimate uses for this, and lots of illegitimate ones.

Comment: Are you sure this question is for StackOverflow? Is this question directly related to programming? Please check out [the site tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome especially protects against this. It does not just have a "cookies folder" so to speak. It also has registry edits, hex codes associated with them and other information to match like date created, date modified etc.

Everything must match for google chrome to consider that cookie as being legitimate. Its a good thing as people would be hijacking sessions everywhere if it were that easy.